# Object.keys(obj).length returning sum of characters not total count of records

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I am trying to count the total number of records returned that are associated with a record entered by the user. In the end, I need to specify an if/else statement determinant on whether more than one record is returned.

Example 1:

User enters record #123456789
Program shows records #223456789 & #333456789 are associated with that record
An info window appears with the link activated to show the associated records

Example 2:
User enters record #000006789
Program shows no records associated
An info window appears without the link to show associated records

Currently the link is still appearing even if no records are associated.

Previously (when count was not a concern; only the existence of an input) the setup for a record that has associated records was:

where compacct is the list of records associated with the user input record

```
    else if ("<%=compacct(0) %>" != ""){
    var salecontent = "";
    var content = "<b>Account Number</b>: " + "<%=number %> "+
    "<center><br><b>Comparable Sales</b></center>"; 

    content = content + salecontent +  
                            "<br><br>" + "<a class='infolink' href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"javascript:getallcommsale(saleaccts)\">Show all Comparable Sales</a>" +
                            "<br>" + "<img src=\"./appFiles/graphics/question3.jpg\" onmouseover=\"this.src='./appFiles/graphics/comp_sales.png';\" onmouseout=\"this.src='./appFiles/graphics/question3.jpg';\"/>" ;
```

I have now modified the code in another section so that all accounts can be entered, not just ones with associated records. The side effect is that now compacct retrieves the user entered record and not just associated records. So I now need to check that the record count for compacct is greater than one. I have tried:

```
    var sale = "<%=compacct(0) %>";
    var saleCount = Object.keys(sale).length;
    if (saleCount > 1){
```

The length retrieved is the sum of the digits in the account and not the total number of accounts

I have also tried:

```
    var sale = "<%=salesstrap(0) %>";
    for (i = 1; i>saleCount.length; i++){
```

but the same problem occurs

Comment: sale is a string not an object? `.length` will be the length of the string?

Comment: Most likely, sale is a string and you are getting the length of that string. Add a console.log(typeof sale) to verify.

Comment: It seems that you're dynamically generating Javascript using something like ASP.NET, going by the `<%= ... %>` syntax. (This is probably a bad idea for a bunch of reasons, I prefer passing data to a script using `data-*` attributes.) What's the resulting value of `sale` supposed to be?

Comment: The length returned is consistently 25. The number of characters in the string for one record in always 13.

Comment: The obligatory question: have you stepped through this code in the browser's Javascript debugger to see what the actual value of `sale` is when this code executes?

Comment: I stepped through and discovered the value is always 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sale` is a `String` in your code examples. `Object.keys()` called on a string will treat the string as an array of characters, and give you the indices valid for that array. I.e.:

```
Object.keys("abc")
```

will return the array:

```
["0", "1", "2"]
```

The length of this array will be the length of the string.

I'm not sure how you expect `sale` to be anything else than a string.

Comment: I expected sale to be an array because I am unfamiliar with javascript. :) Thank you for clarifying what was occurring. I was able to solve the problem and gain the outcome desired by modifying the definition of sale.